# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ViewFlipper

Tags: android

I'm adding a `ViewFlipper` inflated from a layout resource into a `ListView` as a `Footer`. Here's my flipper layout (Details omitted for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper ...>
    <Button
        />
    <LinearLayout 
        ... >
        <ProgressBar 
           ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

I add it to my ListView using :

```
mListView.addFooterView(mLoadMoreFlipper);
```

When my activity is destroyed I see the following message, followed by a call stack, in LogCat:

```
 Activity com.gk.ItemListActivity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@44c84ab0 
 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

I did some digging around and found out the message is related to not unregistering receivers, except I haven't registered any. Oddly this message only appears if the footer `ViewFlipper` has been removed from the `ListView` before destruction (by using the back button). I detach the footer when I no longer need it by using:

```
mListView.removeFooterView(mLoadMoreFlipper);
```

I have tried using a `WeakReference` to the `ViewFlipper` but that doesn't help. I also tried setting the `mLoadMoreFlipper` reference to `null` but that doesn't help either.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? This seems to be related to my activity holding a reference to the `ViewFlipper` after it's been detached from the `ListView` but I do not know how to explicitly destroy the `ViewFlipper`.

Comment: I don't see anything that would necessarily cause that with the code here. Do you register any other callbacks or listeners that have anything to do with the contents of the footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [View Flipper Throws Exception in ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923935/view-flipper-throws-exception-in-viewflipper-ondetachedfromwindow/8938345#8938345). Apparently there is a bug in ViewFlipper. The contains the workaround.