# View Flipper Throws Exception in ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow

Tags: android

I have a `ViewFlipper` in my `Activity` that is used as a footer view of a `ListView`. I had posted a while back regarding an issue I was seeing in the emulator. See [Activity has leaked IntentReceiver android.widget.ViewFlipper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701042/activity-has-leaked-intentreceiver-android-widget-viewflipper). I found an answer to that yet.

Now, I'm seeing problems when debugging on a device. Essentially when device configuration change (rotation) causes my activity to be destroyed, I get a crash. See log.

```
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: android.widget.ViewFlipper$1@4076f0c0
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:610)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:840)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:331)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.widget.ViewFlipper.onDetachedFromWindow(ViewFlipper.java:104)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:6173)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1164)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:1162)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewRoot.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRoot.java:1748)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewRoot.doDie(ViewRoot.java:2759)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.ViewRoot.die(ViewRoot.java:2729)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:218)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeViewImmediate(Window.java:436)
01-19 14:56:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(30240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2705)
```

Interestingly if the debugger is not attached this problem does not occur as often. This is crippling me.

From what I can see `ViewFlipper::onDetachedFromWindow` is trying to unregister a receiver which is not registered. This `ViewFlipper` has been removed from the `ListView` using `removeFooterView` before `ViewFlipper::onDetachedFromWindow` is called.

This is what I use to remove the viewFlipper from the list view:

```
mLoadMoreFlipper.stopFlipping();
mLoadMoreFlipper.removeAllViews();
getExpandableListView().removeFooterView(mLoadMoreFlipper);
mLoadMoreFlipper = null;
```

Is there any other way to force destroy a view. I've tried `WindowManager.removeView` but that throws an exception saying `the view has not been registered with WindowManager`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have this problem too. Look the solution I got : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050730/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm still getting the exceptions. Oddly my `onDetachedFromWindow` override is never called.

Comment: Got a handle on the `onDetachFromWindow` problem at least. Testing now.

Comment: Seems to fix the problem. Thank you so much. Please enter this as an answer and I will reward you the points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem as I had few time ago. I found this solution http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2010/05/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered.html but I didn't understand how to use it. So, I get the answer from here [ViewFlipper : Receiver not registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050730/viewflipper-receiver-not-registered) and my problem has been solved. Try it! I'm sure this solution will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this reproduced on screen rotate when `viewFlipper` runs animation. By some reason `onDetachedFromWindow()` method is not called on such `viewFlipper`.

I have fixed this by calling `m_viewFlipper.clearAnimation()` in `MyActivity.onPause()` method.

Alternatively one can extend `ViewFlipper` class and override `onSaveInstanceState()` method adding there `clearAnimation()` call.